# HTTP post with swift. Basic IoT App

Tags: html, ios, swift, post, iot

I've never been into programming, but recently for a school project (I'm studying Industrial Design, so I have no background in software) I'm trying to port this code to a basic iOs app. Just the POST action, not the format.

```
center><br>
<br>
<br>
<form action="https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/your-device-ID-goes-here/led?access_token=your-access-token-goes-here" method="POST">
Tell your device what to do!<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="args" value="on">Turn the LED on.
<br>
<input type="radio" name="args" value="off">Turn the LED off.
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!">
</form>
</center>
```

This is what I have, but now I'm.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/your-device-ID-goes-here/led?access_token=your-access-token-goes-here")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL:myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"







    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope to serve you see this "FrameWork"

```
https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP
```

if you make a post, missing parameters ...
it would have to see this.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.thisismylink.com/postName.php"))
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
data, response, error in

if error != nil {
    println("error=\(error)")
    return
}

println("response = \(response)")

let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```